# Team Foundation Server 2012 subscribe to events

Tags: plugins, customization

In my case I need subscribe to TFS events (create/delete team project, workitem, checkin, iteration, areas) for realization some business logic. I based on [this manual](http://vgaltes.com/index.php/2013/04/14/create-a-team-foundation-server-event-handler/). Now I can catch only workitem and checkin events, but I need more (team project, iteration, areas). In [this list](http://nakedalm.com/tfs-event-handler-for-team-foundation-server-2010/), I did not find the right events.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Integration.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;

public class WorkItemChangedEventHandler : ISubscriber
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "WorkItemChangedEventHandler"; }
    }

    public SubscriberPriority Priority
    {
        get { return SubscriberPriority.Normal; }
    }

    public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
    {
        var types = new List<Type>
        {
            typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemChangedEvent),// working
            typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.CheckinNotification),// working
            typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Integration.Server.ProjectCreatedEvent)// NOT working

        };
        return types.ToArray();
    }

    public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType,
        object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
    {
        statusCode = 0;
        properties = null;
        statusMessage = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("WorkItemChangedEventHandler", string.Format("Entity: {0} was modified", notificationEventArgs.GetType()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("WorkItemChangedEventHandler", ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one class for CheckinNotificationEventHandler:

```
public class CheckinNotificationEventHandler : ISubscriber
{
        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[1] { typeof(CheckinNotification) };
        }
        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is CheckinNotification)
            {
        ...
            }
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }
}
```

and a second class for WorkItemChangedEventHandler:

```
   public class WorkItemChangedEventHandler : ISubscriber
    {

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[1] { typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemChangedEvent) };
        }

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {

            if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
            {
            ...
            }
        return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }
     }
```